# Ant - javac task - classpath is not taking the jars

Tags: java, ant, testng

I have my ant `build.xml` file like this:

```
<!-- Properties -->
<property name="src" value="${basedir}" />
<property name="jars" value="${src}/jars" />
<property name="dest" value="${src}/dest" />
<property name="reports" value="${src}/reports" />

<path id="claspath">
    <fileset dir="${jars}">
        <include name="*.jar" />
    </fileset>
</path>

<target name="clean">
    <echo> removing the directories "dest" and "reports" </echo>
    <delete dir="${dest}" />
    <delete dir="${reports}" />
</target>

<target name="makedir" depends="clean">
    <echo> creating directories "dest" and "reports" </echo>
    <mkdir dir="dest" />
    <mkdir dir="reports" />
</target>

<target name="complie" depends="makedir">
    <javac srcdir="${src}" destdir="${dest}" />
    <classpath refid="classpath"/>
</target>
```

When I type `ant` command in cmd prompt the compiling happens but the jar files are not loading so I am getting compiling errors. The jar folder that i have mentioned in the above code has only one jar file which is "testng-6.8.5.jar". Please let me know what is wrong in the above code.

Comment: there is a small typo error in the above code.. For the target "compile" the refid that i have mentioned for classpath is incorrect. It was just a typo error.

Comment: you can edit your own question to fix the typos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're closing the `<javac>` tag on the same line, it should be:

```
<javac srcdir="${src}" destdir="${dest}">
        <classpath refid="classpath"/>
</javac>
```